# YEAR(begin_date) unknown column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, MONTH(begin_date)
FROM `events`
WHERE (YEAR(begin_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())) 
      OR (YEAR(begin_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1)  
GROUP BY MONTH(begin_date)
```

Here is sql query, i want to write it in laravel eloquent.

what i try:

```
  $oncoming_events = DB::table('events')    
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as numOfOncomingEvents, MONTH(begin_date)'))    
    ->where('YEAR(begin_date)', '=',  'YEAR(CURDATE())')
    ->orWhere('YEAR(begin_date)', '=', 'YEAR(CURDATE()) +1')
    ->groupBy('MONTH(begin_date)')->get();
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEAR(begin_date)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as numOfOncomingEvents, MONTH(begin_date) from `events` where `YEAR(begin_date)` =

laravel 5.6

btw 
sql query works..

Comment: you can use `whereYear('begin_date', date('Y'))`

Comment: what is date('Y') ?

Comment: it returns current year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DB::raw()` in where to tell the query builder that it is not column name it is data manipulation in query,

`$oncoming_events = DB::table('events')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as numOfOncomingEvents, MONTH(begin_date)'))->where(DB::raw('YEAR(begin_date)'), '=',  'YEAR(CURDATE())')->orWhere(DB::raw('YEAR(begin_date)'), '=', 'YEAR(CURDATE()) +1')->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(begin_date)'))->get();`